# JQM: taphold event does not prevent click event

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I'm trying to bind taphold event on a link under JQM.

Problem, that occurs is, that if user, doing his long click, releases mouse over this link - also the click event is fired. What of course not intended - I want to separate these events.

So I have a link like this:

```
<a href="do-smth">link</a>
```

and something else, that should be done on long tap

```
$("a").on("taphold", function(event) {do_smth_else()});
```

and both `do-smth` and `do_smth_else` are executed, when user makes a long tap and releases mouse over link.

Here http://jsfiddle.net/GardenOfEmuna/68r4gph6/1/ is the example.

Does anyone have a remedy against it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no other way than [preventing the default behavior](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) of the [vclick](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/) event:

```
$(".link").on({
    taphold: function() {
        post('long tap fired');
    },
    vclick: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This way, the `taphold` handlers will be invoked but the default action associated with the link will be canceled.

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/68r4gph6/2/).

If you want the default behavior of the link to still occur, but only if a long tap was not performed, you will have to associate state with the element itself. jQuery's [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) facility allows you to write:

```
$(".link").on({
    taphold: function() {
        post('long tap fired');
        $(this).data("longTapRegistered", true);
    },
    "vclick vmouseout": function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (e.type == "vclick" && $this.data("longTapRegistered")) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        $this.removeData("longTapRegistered");
    }
});
```

Note we also have to remove our persisted state on [vmouseout](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vmouseout/) to avoid the issue you described in your comment.

You will find a fiddle demonstrating this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/68r4gph6/4/).

Comment: still there is a problem, when person makes a long tap drags and releases mouse not over link, then next simple click is not fired.

Comment: @Daniel, you're absolutely right. Event delegation might be able to solve this, I'll give a try and update my answer upon success.

Comment: @Daniel, unfortunately event delegation cannot buy us anything here, but "forgetting" the long tap on `vmouseout` fixes the problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be working on JQuery 1.11.1... onclick event is fired as soon as the mouse is released, and before the vclick event is fired.